# Canvas as drag feedback image doesn't work in webkit

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drag-and-drop

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_Operations#Setting_the_drag_feedback_image) says:

> The first is a reference to an image. This reference will typically be
>   to an image element but it can also be to a **canvas** or any other
>   element.

So I simply created code in dragStart event:

```
di = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml","canvas")
diCtx = di.getContext("2d")

tmp = $('#img')[0]
diCtx.width = tmp.naturalWidth + xAdd*(count-1)
diCtx.height = tmp.naturalHeight + yAdd*(count-1)

e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(di, 25, 25)
```

It's working perfect in Firefox. But in Chrome and Opera Next (both Webkit) doesn't.
I tried to do it around:

```
di = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml","canvas")
diCtx = di.getContext("2d")

tmp = $('#img')[0]
diCtx.width = tmp.naturalWidth + xAdd*(count-1)
diCtx.height = tmp.naturalHeight + yAdd*(count-1)

tmp = document.createElement('img')
tmp.src = di.toDataUrl()
di = tmp

e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(di, 25, 25)
```

But I'm getting CORS security error... :/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
// capitalize URL
tmp.src=di.toDataURL();
```

But anyway, your problem occurs when you do di.toDataURL.

Your images must be hosted on the same domain as the webpage you're serving.

Otherwise you get CORS errors for very valid security reasons.

Alternatively you can host your images on a CORS friendly site like dropbox.com.

Then you can load your images with the crossOrigin flag set to `anonymous` and you won't get CORS errors when you try to encode the canvas with toDataURL.